# Should I amend merge commits to make tests pass?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

Recently, I stumbled across [this](https://drewdevault.com/2019/02/25/Using-git-with-discipline.html) article. It mentions that:

> Additionally, every commit should compile and run all tests successfully, and should avoid having any known bugs which will be fixed up in a future commit.

It got me thinking. Sometimes, after I merge `develop` into the `feature` branch, even though I have no conflicts, I still have to adjust some code, so it works with my changes and all tests pass.

**My question is, what would be the preferable way of doing that?**

- amending merge commit
- or creating a brand new commit

I don't feel like it's a good idea to sneak additional code in merge commits, but if I don't do that, this commit will have "known bugs" that I should avoid, right?

I'd love to hear some practical/real-life arguments, how does it influence working with `git-bisect`? (I haven't used it yet, but I know it exists and might come handy one day)

Comment: I agree adding code to a merge is probably not best. I'd add a commit to feature and merge it into develop. Similar to the hotfix workflow. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: You should merge the feature branch into develop (or rebase the development branch on top of the feature) and run your tests, *then* merge into the feature branch.

Comment: That sounds like a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, the ideal way to deal with this is to get the fix commits into the development / feature branch before merging.  For instance:

```
...--o---------------------M   <-- master
      \                   /
       o--o--o--o--o--o--*   <-- develop
```

where commit `*` is the fixup needed to make the merge go smoothly and produce a working merge commit `M`.

In practice, it's often that not that big a deal either way.  If commit `M` would fail existing tests, a CI system will enforce this best-practice and all will be fine—but what if the thing that actually fails in `M` is *new*, a failure that's never been observed before and was unanticipated?  The CI system won't notice, and neither will you, until you get to some commit `X`:

```
                                o--o--X   <-- topic
                               /
...--o------------------M--o--o--...-o   <-- master
      \                /
       o--o--o--o--o--o
```

and now you discover that, oops, we should have had a test for that.  So now you can add the test, but you can't go back and change `M`, nor any of its descendants.  The ideal way to fix this is to check out the first point at which the bug occurs, on a new test-and-fix branch, write the test and the fixes, and keep that as a handy branch, e.g.:

```
                                o--o--X   <-- topic
                               /
...--o------------------M--o--o--...-o   <-- master
      \                /
       o--o--o--o--o--o
                    \
                     F1--F2   <-- test-and-fix
```

Commit `F1` has the new test (which fails) and `F2` fixes it.  You can now `git checkout master; git merge test-and-fix` *and* `git checkout topic; git merge test-and-fix` to bring the fixes into `master` and each topic/development branch.

(Actually drawing the resulting graph gets painful.)

In practice a lot of people just cherry-pick a fix made at the end of `master`:

```
                                o--o--X--F12'   <-- topic
                               /
...--o------------------M--o--o--...-o-------F12   <-- master
      \                /              \      /
       o--o--o--o--o--o                F1--F2   <-- test-and-fix
```

where `F12'` is the cherry-pick of the combination / merge `F12`, and that generally works OK.  But making the fix early, at the point at which the bug was first created, is at least *theoretically* better.  See [Raymond Chen's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325)  for more about this.